# Phpunit 10 - flags not respected

Tags: phpunit

I've just updated phpunit to version 10.2; when running `vendor/bin/phpunit --testdox` I'm still seeing results in plain format; running `vendor/bin/phpunit --stop-on-failure` will not stop the test runner, etc

I'm on Mac, with PHP 8.2.1; this is with Laravel 10

Comment: `--testdox` was removed in PHPUnit 10, the reasons for doing so is beyond me. The answer given by the owner is to write your own testdox.